# Pass form data to PHP script with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following form I've been working on.

Now, I'm unsure how to grab the form data and push it to my `update.php` script.

I'd like my `update.php` script to loop through the rows in `index.php` and output the *account_name* value for each.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="exampleTable" class="row effects text-center">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tg-yw4l">Reference</th>
                    <th class="tg-yw4l">Account Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="row-id-139">
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">123</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" class="account_name" value="John Johnson"></td>
                </tr>
                    
                <tr class="row-id-140">
                    <td class="tg-yw4l">123</td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" class="account_name" value="Jack Thomson"></td>
                </tr>            
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form action="" method="post" class="revise">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-xl" value="Update"/>
</form>
<div class="refund-content"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.revise').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var data = new FormData();

    // process the form
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'update.php?action=edit',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        complete: function (data) {
            $('.refund-content').html("<br><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Updated.</div>");
            console.log(data);
        }
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's in there :-) `<form action="" method="post" class="revise">`

Comment: Come to that, I dont see a `</head>` or a `<body>`

Comment: Oh yea! Its only got a button in it. All the `<input>` fields need to be inside it also

Comment: The form is pointless, since you want to send all those values via ajax

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried to move `<form action="" method="post" class="revise">` further up the page but it still doesn't push the data through.

Comment: @GetSet What would be a better workaround? :-)

Comment: Collect the values, mutate to JSON, then provide that as your `data` to your ajax call

Comment: Light reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: @GetSet Would you be able to guide me to tutorials for this or perhaps post a simple solution as an Answer? Thank you

Comment: If you want to access the inputs using JS and not a simple form submit the Input fields will need a `id` attribute at least. If you want to submit normally, they also need a `name` attribute

Comment: @RiggsFolly Aaah - so perhaps it would make sense to set the id to be `account_name_rownumber`?

Comment: Remember, the id's have to be unique on the page, dup id's will cause you issues and heart ache

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yep, that's why I thought it would make sense to use the row id in the id :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226674/discussion-between-michaelmcgurk-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: confused but why are the `<input>` fields outside of the `<form></form>` element tags? If you use the form element you can use jquery to serialize the form. `var data = $('form.revise').serialize()` You would need to rename the input names to an array `name="account_name[]"` or `name="account[<?php echo $id; ?>]name"`

Comment: @WillB.Could you possibly amend my script to show this? I've tried but been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment and depending on your intention behind the form submission, you would want to use the `<form>` to allow for jQuery to [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and submit the data to the specified URL.

Below I use a pseudo database result as the `$accounts` array, in order to output each of the accounts within your form.

I also optimized the code based on standard practices such as escaping the database values using `htmlentities` or [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) being output in your HTML code, to ensure they do not break the DOM with the single or double quotes.

*/index.php*

```
<?php 
//psuedo database values

$accounts = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Johnson'),
    array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Jack Thomson'),
);

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<form action="/update.php?action=edit" method="post" class="revise">
    <div id="exampleTable" class="row effects text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="tg-yw4l">Reference</th>
                    <th class="tg-yw4l">Account Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($accounts as $i => $account) { ?>
                <tr class="row-id-<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $account['id']; ?></td>
                    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input type="text" name="account[<?php echo $account['id']; ?>]name" class="account_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($account['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>

    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-xl">Update</button
</form>
<div class="refund-content" style="display:none;">
    <br><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Updated.</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    var editForm = $('form.revise');
    editForm.on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        $('.refund-content').hide();
        var data = editForm.serialize();
        var url = editForm.attr('action');

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            cache: false,
        }).done(function (response) {
           $('.refund-content').show();
           console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now you can retrieve the `$_POST` results in update.php.

*/update.php*

```
//debugging
var_dump($_POST);
/* should output:
array(
    'account' => array(
        '1' => ['name' => 'John Johnson'],
        '2' => ['name' => 'Jack Thomson'],
    )
);
*/

//processing
if (isset($_GET['action']) && 'edit' === $_GET['action']) {
   if (!empty($_POST) && array_key_exists('account', $_POST)) {
      foreach ($_POST['account'] as $id => $account) {
          echo $id . ' ' . $account['name'] . PHP_EOL;
      }
   }
}
```

---

**Special considerations**: PHP by default has a limited amount of input values that can be requested at one time. Please update your form pagination or PHP [`max_input_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) and [`post_max_size`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) configuration accordingly to prevent missing data.